# Сортировка данных с помощью DateTimePicker по диапазону дат

Tags: access, delphi

Использую базу данных аксесс, компоненты `ADOConnection, ADOQuery, ADODataSource, DBGrid`, пара `DateTimePicker` и одна `BitBtn`. В обработку `BitBtn` пишу:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var  Date1,Date2:string;
begin
Date1:= DateTimePicker1.DateTime;
Date2:= DateTimePicker2.DateTime;
Form1.ADOQuery1.Active:= False;
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT *FROM Расходник');
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE Дата_прихода');
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('BETWEEN ('+Date1+') AND ('+Date2+')');
Form1.ADOQuery1.Active:= True;    
end;    
end.
```

`ADOQuery`, в параметрах завожу 2 параметра, `Date1` и `Date2`, у обоих в `DataType` стоит `ftDateTime`.

Не фурычит никак. (( Полазил по форумам, вроде все то пишут... Может, чего недопонял?
Помогите.

**Добавлено.**

Обработчик событий не фурычит... С SQL запросом все ок. Прописываешь в SQL на ADOQuery

```
SELECT *FROM Расходник
WHERE Дата_прихода BETWEEN '11.06.2010' AND '12.02.2011'
```

Все фильтрует, а обработчик не идет (( Что там не так?

Answer (score 1):

В конструкции `var Date1, Date2:string;` нужно использовать не String, а DateTime: `var Date1, Date2:DateTime;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var  Date1,Date2:string;

Date1:= DateTimePicker1.DateTime;
Date2:= DateTimePicker2.DateTime;
```

Вы переменным типа `String` присваиваете значение `TDateTime`;

```
Date1:= DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.DateTime);
Date2:= DateToStr(DateTimePicker2.DateTime);
```

Comment: Сделал так но застревает на параметрах

Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date1').Value:= DateTimePicker1.DateTime;
Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date2').Value:= DateTimePicker2.DateTime;

B ADOQuery в Parameters стоит Date1 и Date2, у обоих в DataType стоит ftDateTime.
Все равно выцдает ошибку (((

Answer (score 0):

Вот как-то так через "Параметры"

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT *FROM Расходник');
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE (Date >=:FromDate) AND (Date <=:ToDate)');
Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('FromDate').Value:= FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yy', Form1.DateTimePicker1.Date);
Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ToDate').Value:= FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yy', Form1.DateTimePicker2.Date);
Form1.ADOQuery1.Close;
Form1.ADOQuery1.Open;

end;    
end.
```